# How to add a "Load More" button to a HTML JSON page

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

so i'm currently working on a project which fetches product information from a JSON file and inputs it onto a HTML page via js. I've managed to get the fetch function working, however I would like to a "Load More" function/button so that my page originally displays 12 (4x3 grid) items and when user clicks on the button it displays the remaining 12 items. I would appreciate any help .Right now as it is its displaying all the data from the json file but I would like it to display the first 12 and then when the user clicks and additional 12 if that makes sense.The first code snippet is from the json file.

```json
`{ "productList": [
    {
        "images": [
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_1_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_2_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_3_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_4_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_5_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454160_6_medium.jpg"
        ],
        "name": "Fringed checked wool-blend coat",
        "designer": "Marni",
        "url": "/products/Marni-Fringed-checked-wool-blend-coat-1454160",
        "price": "£1,790",
        "index": 0,
        "code": "1454160"
    },
    {
        "images": [
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_1_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_2_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_3_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_4_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_5_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454112_6_medium.jpg"
        ],
        "name": "Shopping logo-jacquard tote bag &amp; leather pouch",
        "designer": "Marni",
        "url": "/products/Marni-Shopping-logo-jacquard-tote-bag-%26-leather-pouch-1454112",
        "price": "£890",
        "index": 1,
        "code": "1454112"
    },
    {
        "images": [
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_1_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_2_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_3_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_4_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_5_medium.jpg",
            "//assetsprx.matchesfashion.com/img/product/1454159_6_medium.jpg"
        ],
        "name": "Suede and silk-knit midi skirt",
        "designer": "Marni",
        "url": "/products/Marni-Suede-and-silk-knit-midi-skirt-1454159",
        "price": "£1,690",
        "index": 2,
        "code": "1454159"
    },
```

```js
fetch("products/products.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.productList.length; i++) {
      console.log(data.productList[i].images);

   
      products =
        products +
        `
      <div class=card>
      <img src="${data.productList[i].images[2]}">
      <h4>${data.productList[i].designer}</h4>
      <p>${data.productList[i].name}</p>
      <p>${data.productList[i].price}</p>


      </div>
      
      `;
    }
    document.querySelector("#myData").innerHTML = products;
    
  }
  );
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* FONT & TYPOGRAPHY STYLES */

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
body,
html,
label {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333447;
  line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* button */
.btncontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
button {
  background-color: #000; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}

/* CLASSES */
.product-img {
  max-width: 90%;
}

/* GRID SYSTEM  */

.container {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}
#myData {
  display: grid;

  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

 
 



@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Product List Front End Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">
      <section class="row">
        <div clas="col-6">
          <h1>Product List Page Test by ______</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="row" id="productList">
        <div id="myData"></div>
      </section>
      <div class="btncontainer">
        <button id="lmbutton">Load more</button>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While the code you post does definitely have to be testable, an example this comprehensive was not neccessary (the amount of unecessary code is actually a bit distracting, not a huge issue in this post though

Comment: Please leave stuff like "Please im desperate" out of question titles. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, but you are calling a variable instead of a function, only function calls are valid after html events, put your javascript in a function and call it

```js
function loadMore() {
  fetch("products/products.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.productList.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.productList[i].images);

        //   if (i <= 11) {
        products =
          products +
          `
      <div class=card>
      <img src="${data.productList[i].images[2]}">
      <h4>${data.productList[i].designer}</h4>
      <p>${data.productList[i].name}</p>
      <p>${data.productList[i].price}</p>


      </div>
      
      `;
      }
      document.querySelector("#myData").innerHTML = products;
      // }
    });
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700);

/* UNIVERSAL */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* FONT & TYPOGRAPHY STYLES */

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
body,
html,
label {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333447;
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* POSITIONING */

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* button */

.btncontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #000;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}


/* CLASSES */

.product-img {
  max-width: 90%;
}


/* GRID SYSTEM  */

.container {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

#myData {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 6%;
    padding-right: 6%;
  }
  .row {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .row:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .col-1 {
    width: 7.05%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 15.5%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 23.95%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 32.4%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 40.85%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 49.3%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 57.75%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.2%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 74.65%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.1%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.55%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 661px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
  .row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .t-col-4,
  .t-col-6,
  .t-col-12 {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .t-col-4 {
    width: 31.46%;
  }
  .t-col-6 {
    width: 48.6%;
  }
  .t-col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row:first-child .t-col-4,
  .row:first-child .t-col-6,
  .row:first-child .t-col-12 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 660px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
  .row {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .m-col-6,
  .m-col-12 {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .m-col-6 {
    width: 47.2%;
  }
  .m-col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .row:first-child .m-col-6,
  .row:first-child .m-col-12 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #myData {
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Product List Front End Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div clas="col-6">
        <h1>Product List Page Test by ______</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row" id="productList">
      <div id="myData"></div>
    </section>
    <div class="btncontainer">
      <button id="lmbutton" onclick="loadMore();">Load more</button>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You might notice I put a `();` after the function call, this is not necessary, with zero parameters and no semicolon it still calls, but since the onload essentially creates a new javaScript context, it would be best practice

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help, however despite putting the function, I dont think i made myself clear . i apologise . but wouldnt I need another function that would allow the user to click on the button  which would display a further 12 items . because right now as it is its displaying all the data from the json file but I would like it to display the first 12 and then when the user clicks and additional 12 if that makes sense ??